# How to define or have Typescript ignore relative ambient modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I'm attempting to load a json file with a custom json loader module. I have babel configured to use my loader specifically for `src/routes.json`, though really it could be for any json file. I've done my best to look at the docs and the multiples issues reported with similar problems of loading vendor library modules but none of the solutions I've found (which are various ways of defining the module) are working for me.

What I'm attempting to do is implement the declarative router found here: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate/blob/master/docs/routing-and-navigation.md

My question is how can I have typescript understand my relative `src/routes.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write something like

```
declare module "*.json";
```

in a global `.ts` or `.d.ts` file. That tells TypeScript "anything that ends in `.json` exists, and I shouldn't get any errors for using it."

To clarify, when I say "a global file", I mean any file that has no imports or exports.

Comment: Thanks! That did it